# What is the design pattern for WordPress Core?

Tags: design

What is the design pattern of [WordPress Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/)? As [this Stack Overflow question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857143/is-wordpress-mvc-compliant), WordPress does *not* follow the MVC pattern; however, developers can write [plugins and themes that follow MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936168/754842). But my question pertains *exclusively* to WordPress Core, not to any additional add-ons, themes, extensions, plugins, or [forked projects](http://wpmvc.org/) that may or may not follow an MVC pattern.

If WordPress Core does not follow an MVC design, then what design pattern does it follow?

Comment: Simply none. There are a bunch of files, with zillion of functions, some classes and a big hope that everything will work.

Comment: Totally agree with @G.M. there is no conclusive, stringent pattern, but of course some design decisions have been made, for example this might be interesting for you: [Wordpress and event-driven programming - what is it about?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/117387/22534).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spaghetti with meatballs

> The term "spaghetti with meatballs" is a pejorative term used in
>   computer science to describe loosely constructed object-oriented
>   programming (OOP) that remains dependent on procedural code. It may be
>   the result of a system whose development has included a long life
>   cycle, language constraints, micro-optimization theatre, or a lack of
>   coherent coding standards.

It also has a bit of macaroni mixed in...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Spaghetti_with_meatballs

Comment: Ayy....LM∀O !!! The term is super funny and it flips many of the ardent WP devs :P

Answer (score 8):

WordPress uses the [Event Driven Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) due to action/hook API.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a singleton design pattern, as there is base class and base object called $wp which is global object.